# Slim-3 php framework shows page not found error even the url is correct?

Tags: php, slim-3

Slim-3 php framework shows page not found error even the url is correct.
I am writing webservice for android application in php using slim3 framework.
few days before it was working fine.same code is not working now.It always returns page not found.i think error in the index.php file but i can't figure it out.

I have tried almost anything that i can get to solve this problem.
I changed the directory structure and .htaccess file but still not solved.i am using xampp server.

```
index.php

<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;


require '../ChickenShop/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../ChickenShop/public/includes/DbOperations.php';


//Creating a new app with the config to show errors
 $app = new \Slim\App([
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
]);


//registering a new user
$app->post('/register', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (isTheseParametersAvailable(array('name', 'email', 'password', 'phone','address'))) {
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();
        $name = $requestData['name'];
        $email = $requestData['email'];
        $password = $requestData['password'];
        $phone = $requestData['phone'];
        $address = $requestData['address'];
        $db = new DbOperations();
        $responseData = array();

        $result = $db->registerUser($name, $email, $password, $phone, $address);

        if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
            $responseData['error'] = false;
            $responseData['message'] = 'Registered successfully';
            $responseData['user'] = $db->getUserByEmail($email);
        } elseif ($result == USER_CREATION_FAILED) {
            $responseData['error'] = true;
            $responseData['message'] = 'Some error occurred';
        } elseif ($result == USER_EXIST) {
            $responseData['error'] = true;
            $responseData['message'] = 'This email already exist, please login';
        }

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($responseData));
    }
});


//user login route
$app->post('/login', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    if (isTheseParametersAvailable(array('email', 'password'))) {
        $requestData = $request->getParsedBody();
        $email = $requestData['email'];
        $password = $requestData['password'];

        $db = new DbOperations();

        $responseData = array();

        if ($db->userLogin($email, $password)) {
            $responseData['error'] = false;
            $responseData['user'] = $db->getUserByEmail($email);
        } else {
            $responseData['error'] = true;
            $responseData['message'] = 'Invalid email or password';
        }

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($responseData));
    }
});

//getting all products
$app->get('/products', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $db = new DbOperations();
    $products = $db->getAllProducts();
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode(array("products" => $products)));
});

//function to check parameters
function isTheseParametersAvailable($required_fields)
{
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;

    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        $response = array();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echo json_encode($response);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Run app
$app->run();
```

URL that i have tried to access:

http://localhost/ChickenShop/public/

```
Content of .htaccess file:



        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

[image: Project directory structure]

i expected it to work fine.

Comment: Anyone alive here... :(

Comment: Your question does not provide clear information. For example, what is url you tried to access, the content of your .htaccess, your project directory structures, etc.

Comment: question is edited.now almost every info is provided.